# Cannot find method of a class?

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, methods

I have this problem:

I have to create three classes, GroceryList, GroceryItemOrder, and GroceryMain, the main class. In my GroceryList class, this error pops up: cannot find symbol - method add(GroceryItemOrder). The error is at list.add(item) in the GroceryList class. What is wrong with my classes? Thanks.

This is GroceryList:

```
    import java.util.*;  

public class GroceryList {  
    private GroceryItemOrder[] list;  
    int num;  

    public GroceryList() {  
        list = new GroceryItemOrder[10];  
        this.num = 0;  
    }  

   public void add(GroceryItemOrder item) {  
        list.add(item);  
   }  

    public double getTotalCost() {  
        double totalcost = 0;  
        for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){  
        totalcost += getGroceryItemOrder(getCost());  
        }        
        return totalcost;  
    }

}
```

And this is GroceryItemOrder:

```
public class GroceryItemOrder {  
private String name;  
private double pricePerUnit;  
private int quantity;  


   public GroceryItemOrder(String name, int quantity, double pricePerUnit) {  
        this.name = name;  
        this.pricePerUnit = pricePerUnit;  
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }  

    public double getCost() {  
        return (this.quantity * this.pricePerUnit);  
    }  

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {  
        this.quantity = quantity;  
    }  

}
```

And this is the main class:

```
    public class GroceryMain {  
  public static void main(String[] args) {  
        GroceryList list = new GroceryList();  
        GroceryItemOrder chips = new GroceryItemOrder("chips", 5, 1.25);  
        list.add(chips);  
        GroceryItemOrder apples = new GroceryItemOrder("apples", 4, 0.50);  
        list.add(apples);  
        GroceryItemOrder oranges = new GroceryItemOrder("oranges", 1, 1.00);  
        list.add(oranges);  
        GroceryItemOrder blueberries = new GroceryItemOrder("blueberries", 10, .05);  
        list.add(blueberries);  
        GroceryItemOrder strawberries = new GroceryItemOrder("strawberries", 1, 4.00);  
        list.add(strawberries);  
        GroceryItemOrder cheese = new GroceryItemOrder("cheese", 1, 3.00);  
        list.add(cheese);  
        GroceryItemOrder chocolate = new GroceryItemOrder("chocolate", 1, 1.50);  
        list.add(chocolate);  
        GroceryItemOrder milk = new GroceryItemOrder("milk", 2, 3.00);  
        list.add(milk);  
        GroceryItemOrder yogurt = new GroceryItemOrder("yogurt", 3, 1.00);  
        list.add(yogurt);  
        GroceryItemOrder tacos = new GroceryItemOrder("tacos", 1, 2.50);  
        list.add(tacos);  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `add` is not available for conventional Arrays.. It is available for `Arraylist`.

```
private GroceryItemOrder[] list;  // Standard Arrays
```

Change it to

```
private ArrayList<GroceryItemOrder> list;
```

Now you can add using `list.add(element)`.

Comment: Now when I change that line, the line: list = new GroceryItemOrder[10]; says incompatible types. Why is that so? Aren't I still just constructing an array? Or what should I change? Thanks.

Comment: list = new ArrayList<GroceryItemOrder>(10);   is the right way to create a arraylist

Comment: Now when I compile GroceryList, this message for totalcost += getGroceryItemOrder(getCost()); shows up: cannot fins symbol getCost(). But the method is defined in GroceryItemOrder. Is my syntax wrong here?

Comment: It shoudld be totalcost += getGroceryItemOrder().getCost();

Comment: It says cannot find symbol: method GroceryItemOrder(). It's searching for the method, but it's getting the wrong one.

Comment: Are you storing GroceryItemOrder as ArrayList or Arrays ?

Comment: private ArrayList <GroceryItemOrder> list; and list = new ArrayList<GroceryItemOrder>(10);. So I guess GroceryItemOrder is stored as ArrayList?

Comment: Try this : list.get(i).getCost()

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Use the value in the for loop as the order number in GroceryItemOrder ArrayList and call the method, then add each subsequent call, right?